# Function as element of list in R

Tags: r, list, function

Can a function be defined as an element of list in R? I came across a proprietary code which did so. How can it be called. 
For eg.

```
myList$myFunc = function(input1){}
```

How is this called?

Comment: `myList$myFunc(x)` ?

Comment: Lists are (pretty much) the most general object in R. They can hold anything that R can store. So you can have lists of vectors, or lists of data.frames or lists of functions, or lists of plot objects, among any other objects as well as mixtures of these objects in the same list.

Comment: Something like this? `x <- list(func1 = function(x) sum(x));
x$func1(1:5)`